# Select within Structs within Arrays in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find rows with `N` count of identifier `A` AND `M` count of identifier `B` in an array of structs within a Google BigQuery table, using the new Standard SQL. The data in the table (simplified) where each row looks a bit like this:

```
{
  "Session": "abc123",
  "Information" [
    {
      "Identifier": "A",
      "Count": 1,      
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "B"
      "Count": 2,      
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "C"
      "Count": 3,      
    }
...
  ]
}
```

I've been struggling to work with the struct in an array. Any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(information) kv WHERE kv IN (('a', 5), ('b', 10)))
```

If to apply to dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abc123' session, [STRUCT('a' AS identifier, 1 AS `count`), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)] information UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc456', [('a', 5), ('b', 10), ('c', 20)]
)
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(information) kv WHERE kv IN (('a', 5), ('b', 10)))
```

result is

```
Row session information.identifier  information.count    
1   abc456  a                       5    
            b                       10   
            c                       20
```